# Spring Cloud Config Server OAuth2 authorization

Tags: keycloak, spring-cloud-config-server, spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client

I have a config server and spring boot microservices running with config server requiring basic authentication user/pw.  I have a Keycloak server I want to use for authentication and authorization of the microservice to the config server.
I have added the keycloak spring boot adapter to the config server so now the config server requires an OAuth2 token and have verified with Postman that it works as expected.

This is my microservice pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo-3</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo-3</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR9</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

this is my bootstrap.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: appAuthzRestSpringBoot
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: ${SOA_CONFIG_URI}
      fail-fast: true
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          keycloak:
            authorization-grant-type: client_credentials
            client-id: app-authz-rest-springboot
            client-secret: secret
        provider:
          keycloak:
            token-uri: http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/spring-boot-quickstart/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

The bootstrap call to the config server does not have an OAuth2 bearer token.
What am I missing?